# Query in mysql Stored Proc falsely returning null

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, select

I am attempting to set a list of variables using a SELECT - INTO statement, however I am hitting some issues with the query returning null data when it should find a row.  The really odd part is, if I select a certain column it works, but it won't work with any of the others.  To isolate the issue one at a time, I have simplified the query.  Here is what I am trying to run:

```
SELECT Product_1 INTO @Product_1
FROM STG_XREF_ELS_PRODUCTS
WHERE MarketName = @ThisMarketName
LIMIT 1;
```

This statement does not work, however if I enter the same exact query but select a different field, it works fine...

```
SELECT MarketName INTO @Product_1
FROM STG_XREF_ELS_PRODUCTS
WHERE MarketName = @ThisMarketName
LIMIT 1;
```

Notably, I have tested to make sure that this is not a case where Product_1 actually is null, there is no instance in my xref table in which Product_1 is null.  Also, if I just select Product_1 from the table with a limit of 1 and no where clause, I still get a null result.

I have also attempted using:

```
set @Product1 = (select Product_1 
                 FROM STG_XREF_ELS_PRODUCTS 
                 WHERE MarketName = @ThisMarketName);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S.

Comment: fyi: The @ notation in MySQL denotes a session variable. In t-sql the @ denotes a local variable. In MySQL local variables do not require any prefix. Be wary of using session variables in MySQL because the value may not be what you expect (I see this a lot with SQL-server people using MySQL, please carry on if this is not the case)

Comment: have you tried it with backticks?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name of the variable so:

SELECT Product_1 INTO @Product_variable
FROM STG_XREF_ELS_PRODUCTS
WHERE MarketName = @ThisMarketName
LIMIT 1;